# where should the "artifacts" folder belong to?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I build my solution within Visual Studio 2015 (ASP.NET 5), it creates 2 "artifacts" folders:

/Solution/artifacts

/Solution/src/artifacts

And when checking the assemblies I found they are all created under /Solution/src/artifacts

Is there anything wrong with my project file doing such, or is that intentionally designed?

thanks.

Comment: Yeah that seems strange, mine all go to /Solution/artifacts, I would not want them under Solution/src

Comment: Also add the `artifacts` folder to your `.gitignore` (or equiv) file. The folder shouldn't be added to source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like /Solution/artifacts

[image: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/_images/solution-files.png]

src folder and artifacts are sibling folder.

Comment: The image url is no longer valid, however it seems the folder structure in .NET Core is fairly customizable,  you can control it in global.json, but obviously as suggested the best is always have root folders as ["src", "test", "artifacts"]  etc.